# Spark - read from s3 with server side encryption (AES)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

One way to create an RDD in java is

```
JavaRDD<String> people = sc.textFile("s3://path");
```

What if the data in s3 is encrypted using Server Side Encryption.
How do we create an RDD then?

Comment: Did you try and failed? Have some stacktrace to show?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using encryption enabled EMR then it should automatically decrypt while processing in EMR from S3.

Comment: this is correct if you're the owner of the bucket. otherwise you may have to pass in a key (which is what I'm trying to figure out now...)